Will the potential on surface of a irregular conducting sphere surface be constant?
We know that potential on surface  due to a regular conducting sphere is constant. But what will it be when the surface is irregular and charge distribution is non-uniform?

I think you mean "uniform" not "constant" - "uniform" means unchanging in space whereas "constant" means unchanging in time, which is not necessarily true here.
If the potential on a conducting surface of any shape were not uniform then there would be a force on any positive charges on the surface directed away from areas of higher potential and towards areas of lower potential (and vice versa for negative charges). Since the surface is perfectly conducting, there is nothing to prevent the charges moving in response to these forces, and this movement of charges would even out any differences in potential on the surface, making it uniform.

It's worth adding that even though the potential within the conducting body is uniform, that does not mean that the electric field immediately outside the body is uniform.
